# How can I check if every word in a sentence starts with a capital letter and ends with ", "?

Tags: javascript, php, validation, input, design-patterns

I have an input type text where I would like to allow the user to type profession names. I want to be in this scheme "Profession1, Profession2, Profession3".That is, start with a capital letter and if there are other values ​​then the word should be followed by a "," and a single space. I've tried html patterns and php functions but unfortunately it doesn't work as I would like.  The important thing is that the user can only enter one value, then it should look like "Profession1" without the spaces after the word and the "," symbol. The last condition also applies to the previous example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you tagged this design-patterns, I’m going to say “don’t bother”. If people enter text weirdly, they look bad, not the site that allowed them to do this. If their profession isn’t capitalized correctly, their name probably isn’t either. Instead, make sure users can edit this data to self-correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicities sake, the below solution does not use regex.

```
function match(str) {
    let list = str.split(' ');
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].charCodeAt(0) > 90 || list[i].charCodeAt(0) < 65) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
        if (!(list[i][list[i].length - 1] == ",")) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

When passed a string containing words separated by commas, with each word starting with a capital letter, it returns the list. Otherwise, it returns false.

Edit: After the clarification of requirements in the comments, below is the updated function.

```
function match(str) {
    let list = str.split(',');

    // Checks for capital letters at the start of each profession
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].trim().charCodeAt(0) > 90 || list[i].trim().charCodeAt(0) < 65) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Checks for spaces after every comma
    for (let i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (!(list[i][0] == " ")) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Trim whitespace on each profession
    l = list.map((profession) => {
        return profession.trim();
    })
    return l;
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly as I wanted, but I forgot to add that some profession names can be multi-component something like ("Profesion profesion" or "Profesion-profesion" )

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer to account for this. If it works, could you possibly mark it as correct?

Comment: Okay, everything works fine. I really appreciate your help

Comment: No worries chief.